# Should my VS Extension use the ".vs" folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am currently working on a VS Extension that stores solution-specific metadata to a SQLite (.db) file.

Can (and should) I be storing this in the new (as of VS2015) `.vs` folder that sits alongside the `.sln` file?  Or is this storage location meant for Microsoft'y, internal visual studio'y things only?

Is there a special API or anything that needs to be utilized or can I just dump a load of files and folders in there?

I've searched and not found any real info about extension development and the utilization of that folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to know if you can stores your VS Extension or SQLite (.db) file in the .vs folder?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I thought my question was pretty clear, but yes that's basically what I'm asking.  Can I and should I? And is it safe to simply write to the filesystem or is there a VS SDK API I should be utilizing or something?  The alternative is for me to create yet another folder in the base SLN folder with my metadata (db) in it.

Comment: I think you're supposed to use the *Folder methods of the WorkspaceHelper extension class, but you have to have an IWorkspace reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.workspace.workspacehelper?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Answer (score 1):

> Should my VS Extension use the “.vs” folder?

Personally, you can use `.vs` folder but not recommend.

Indeed, there is no specific documentation for the folder `.vs`. AFAIK, this `.vs` folder was not invented by the Visual Studio developer team. It is there because someone asked for it. and many other Visual Studio users on the [Visual Studio UserVoice page](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/6079923-store-project-related-information-in-vs-folder-to). The IDE team looked at it, thought it through, accepted it and implemented it. This should be the reason why there is no specific documentation for this folder.

Usually, `.vs` folder is required by Visual Studio to store opened documents, breakpoints, and other information about state of your solution. So, it looks like a normal folder without any other special restrictions, you could use it.

But this `.vs` will sometimes be deleted and regenerated to solve some issue, and the folder is not intended for source control, source control ignore this `.vs` folder by default. So, it should not the best solution to use `.vs` folder.

Comment: Thanks Leo. For now I will continue using my own folder, but I may reconsider later. I think this ext may fit the candidates you described for "what belongs in .vs".  My extension will use a sqlite DB to store local copies of changes to files.  It should not ever get checked into source control, and if it gets cleared out, that's ok (as long as the user is ok with losing local history).  Pre-VS2015, it was common to  have half a dozen (give or take) various folders or files alongside the sln file for different extensions and I don't want to add to that annoying problem.

Comment: @AdamPlocher, Thanks for your info `My extension will use a sqlite DB to store local copies of changes to files. It should not ever get checked into source control, and if it gets cleared out, that's ok`. I do not know it until you told me. If this is not a question, you can try to use `.vs` folder, but I am not sure if it pull in any other question. If you have any problems, let me know for free, I am also interesting in it too :).